# How to add Non-Transitive Properties in OWL with Jena for knowledge infence

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, inference

I made this code to create relation between objects.

```java
OntClass Object = m.createClass(NS + Constants.Object);

ObjectProperty left = m.createObjectProperty(NS + Constants.left);
left.addDomain(Object);
left.addRange(Object);

ObjectProperty right = m.createObjectProperty(NS + Constants.right);
right.addDomain(Object);
right.addRange(Object);
```

As output, I got

```xml
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.mydomain.com/ns1.owl#left">
  <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.mydomain.com/ns1.owl#Object"/>
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.mydomain.com/ns1.owl#Object"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.mydomain.com/ns1.owl#right">
  <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.mydomain.com/ns1.owl#Object"/>
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.mydomain.com/ns1.owl#Object"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

I want to add restriction on these Object properties and make them Non-Transitive.  For example, if I have three objects O1, O2 & O3, I can infer that:

O1 left O2, O2 right O1, O2 left O3, O3 right O2.

[image]

and do not permit O1 left O3 & O3 right O1.

[image]

I found there's the possibility to create transitive properties but for non-transitive ones I didn't know how to do.

Additionally, how can I add a cardinality restriction to represent one object by side.

Comment: I think not giving owl:TransitiveProperty is sufficient to make it non-transitive. I am not sure I understand the last part. If you want only one value per object add owl:cardinality as 1 for the object. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#cardinality-def)

Comment: @alibenmessaoud It depends exactly what you mean by "non-transitive".  If you mean "if p(A,B) and p(B,C), then it is definitely not the case that p(A,C)," there's not a standard OWL construction for that.  If you simply mean, "if p(A,B) and p(B,C), then it's not necessarily the case that p(A,C)", then the previous comment is correct:  just don't make it a transitive property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### FunctionalProperties and MinCardinality Restrictions

Based on you image, it looks like you're trying to represent something like a doubly-linked list.  While you can, in OWL, make a property transitive, there's not a construction to say about a property *p* that:

> **(A)**    *p*(a,b) ∧ *p*(b,c) → ¬*p*(a,c).

By simply not declaring the property transitive, you can have *p*(a,b) and *p*(b,c) and remain agnostic, so to speak, as to whether or not *p*(a,c) holds.  However, in the case that it looks like you're describing, it sounds like you want your *left* and *right* properties to be functional.  When a property *p* is functional, it means that:

> **(B)**    *p*(a,b) ∧ *p*(a,c) → b = c

The logically equivalent contrapositive, of course, is that:

> **(C)**    b ≠ c → ¬*p*(a,b) ∨¬*p*(a,c)

I think that's what you want here, because if you have:

> 1. functional(*left*)
> 2. *left*(o<sub>1</sub>,o<sub>2</sub>)
> 3. *left*(o<sub>2</sub>,o<sub>3</sub>)
> 4. o<sub>1</sub> ≠ o<sub>2</sub>
> 5. o<sub>1</sub> ≠ o<sub>3</sub>
> 6. o<sub>2</sub> ≠ o<sub>3</sub>

Then from **(C)** and (6), we can infer that

> ¬ *left*(o<sub>1</sub>,o<sub>2</sub>) ∨ ¬ *left*(o<sub>1</sub>,o<sub>3</sub>)

but then, by (2), we have

> ¬ *left*(o<sub>1</sub>,o<sub>3</sub>)

which, I think, is the "non-transitivity" that you wanted.  This also restricts each node to having at most one value for the *left* property.  If you also want to ensure that each node has *at least* one value for the *left* property, you can use a minimum cardinality restriction:

> *Node* ⊑  ≥1 *left*

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.ObjectProperty;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

public class MinCardinalityExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String NS = "http://stackoverflow.com/q/22589068/1281433/";
        OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
        model.setNsPrefix( "", NS );

        OntClass node = model.createClass( NS+"Node" );

        ObjectProperty left = model.createObjectProperty( NS+"left" )
                .convertToFunctionalProperty()
                .asObjectProperty();

        node.addSuperClass( model.createMinCardinalityRestriction( null, left, 1 ));

        model.write( System.out, "TTL" );
    }
}
```

```
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

:Node   a                owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  [ a                   owl:Restriction ;
                           owl:minCardinality  "1"^^xsd:int ;
                           owl:onProperty      :left
                         ] .

:left   a       owl:FunctionalProperty , owl:ObjectProperty .
```

### ExactCardinality Restrictions

Of course, note that a property being functional is really the same thing as a maximum cardinality restriction and a subclass axiom by which you say that *everything* is such that it has at most one value for the property:

> ⊤ ⊑ ≤ 1 *p*    is the same as    functional(*p*).

For your *left* property, you might take a simpler route and just assert that each *Node* has exactly one value for the *left* property:

> Node ⊑ = 1 *left*

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.ObjectProperty;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

public class ExactlyCardinalityExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String NS = "http://stackoverflow.com/q/22589068/1281433/";
        OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
        model.setNsPrefix( "", NS );
        OntClass node = model.createClass( NS+"Node" );
        ObjectProperty left = model.createObjectProperty( NS+"left" );
        node.addSuperClass( model.createCardinalityRestriction( null, left, 1 ));
        model.write( System.out, "TTL" );
    }
}
```

```
@prefix :      <http://stackoverflow.com/q/22589068/1281433/> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

:Node   a                owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  [ a                owl:Restriction ;
                           owl:cardinality  "1"^^xsd:int ;
                           owl:onProperty   :left
                         ] .

:left   a       owl:ObjectProperty .
```